# How to count how many time some specific names appear in an Excel sheet using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, count

I want to code a program that tells me how many times the names I have in an Excel file appear. I'll try to explain it better.
I have a list of 200 technicians that went to approximately 2000 appointments. I want my program to tell me that X tech went to y appointments and so on for every and each technician.

I tried using COUNTIF() on Excel but I have too many names to find every time so I was looking for a faster and more efficent solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot the issues you experience.

Comment: UNIQUE() can be used to give you a list of unique names based on the total list. Excel help explains the use. But a count of names is not the same as a count of how many names went to  or Y. Try COUNTIFS()

Answer (score 0):

I created a small sample data to show you how it is done. You can use pandas to count the number of unique technicians and appointments:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"tech": ["Sam", "Ben", "Jen", "Alice", "Dave"]*9,
                    "appointment":list('aaccaaabbcccbbbdcccdddcddddaaabbbdddccaaabbbd')})
df
```

Output:

```
      tech appointment
0     Sam           a
1     Ben           a
2     Jen           c
3   Alice           c
4    Dave           a
5     Sam           a
6     Ben           a
7     Jen           b
8   Alice           b
9    Dave           c
10    Sam           c
11    Ben           c
12    Jen           b
13  Alice           b
14   Dave           b
15    Sam           d
16    Ben           c
17    Jen           c
18  Alice           c
19   Dave           d
20    Sam           d
21    Ben           d
22    Jen           c
23  Alice           d
...
41    Ben           b
42    Jen           b
43  Alice           b
44   Dave           d
```

Now you can groupby the name of technicians and their appointments and count the number of occurrence of each instance:

```
df = df.groupby(['tech', 'appointment'], as_index=False).value_counts()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   tech appointment  count
0   Alice           a      2
1   Alice           b      3
2   Alice           c      2
3   Alice           d      2
4     Ben           a      2
5     Ben           b      2
6     Ben           c      3
7     Ben           d      2
8    Dave           a      3
9    Dave           b      1
10   Dave           c      1
11   Dave           d      4
12    Jen           a      1
13    Jen           b      4
14    Jen           c      4
15    Sam           a      3
16    Sam           b      1
17    Sam           c      1
18    Sam           d      4
```